# linear equation? Calculus review?

Tags: calculus

I can't nail this problem...

The given equation is either linear or equivalent to a linear equation. Solve the equation. (If there is no solution, enter NO SOLUTION. If all real numbers are solutions, enter REALS.)

$$\sqrt{3x} + \sqrt{12}= \frac{x+3}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Thanks for helping if you can!

Comment: Is that "sqrt3x" supposed to be $\sqrt3x$ or $\sqrt{3x}$?  You can get the first by writing `$\sqrt{3}x$` and the second by writing `$\sqrt{3x}$`. [Instructions for writing mathematics on this site are here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

1. Multiply each side of the equation by $\sqrt{3}$:

   $3\sqrt{x}+6=x+3$
2. Subtract $x+3$ from each side of the equation:

   $-x+3\sqrt{x}+3=0$
3. Replace $\sqrt{x}$ with $t$:

   $-t^2+3t+3=0$
4. Find the roots of the quadratic equation:

   $t_{1,2}=\dfrac{-3\pm\sqrt{9+12}}{-2}\approx-0.79,3.79$
5. Replace $t$ with $\sqrt{x}$:

   - $\sqrt{x}\approx-0.79 \implies x\not\in\mathbb{R}$
   - $\sqrt{x}\approx3.79 \implies x\approx14.37$

---

[image]

Comment: wow, so clean explanation.

Comment: @doniyor: Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you say the equation is linear I'll assume it's
$$
\sqrt{3}x + \sqrt{12} = x + 3/\sqrt{3}
$$
This can be simplified to 
$$
\sqrt{3}x + 2\sqrt{3} = x + \sqrt{3}
$$
from which it follows that
$$
(\sqrt{3}-1)x =-\sqrt{3}
\\ x =-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-1} \approx -2.366
$$

---

EDIT. The question has now changed, but since the equation is stated to be linear I suspect it should be
$$
\sqrt{3}x + \sqrt{12} = \frac{x + 3}{\sqrt{3}}
$$
to which the solution is
$$
x = -\tfrac{3}{2}
$$

Comment: Using $x=−2.366$ gives $6.128$ on the left side of the equation and $0.366$ on the right side of the equation, so this is clearly not the correct solution.

Comment: That's because the question changed after I posted the answer!

Comment: That's not right, I agree.

Comment: It's $\sqrt{3x}$ in the question, not $\sqrt{3}x$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the idea:

Multiply both sides by $\sqrt{3}$ to get $$3\sqrt{x}+6=x+3$$

Now let $x=y^2$ and solve for $y$ (and then for $x$).